Check for equality across N (N>2) columns horizontally in Polars
Assume I have the following Polars DataFrame:
all_items = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "ISO_codes": ["fin", "nor", "eng", "eng", "swe"],   
        "ISO_codes1": ["fin", "nor", "eng", "eng", "eng"],    
        "ISO_codes2": ["fin", "ice", "eng", "eng", "eng"],   
        "OtherColumn": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],         
    })

How can I implement a method like check_for_equality along the lines of
def check_for_equality(all_items, columns_to_check_for_equality):
    return all_items.with_columns(
        pl.col_equals(columns_to_check_for_equality).alias("ISO_EQUALS")

    )

So that when I call it:
columns_to_check_for_equality = ["ISO_codes", "ISO_codes1", "ISO_codes2"]

resulting_df = check_for_equality(all_items, columns_to_check_for_equality)

I achieve the following:
resulting_df == pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "ISO_codes": ["fin", "nor", "eng", "eng", "swe"],   
            "ISO_codes1": ["fin", "nor", "eng", "eng", "eng"],    
            "ISO_codes2": ["fin", "ice", "eng", "eng", "eng"],   
            "OtherColumn": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],    
            "ISO_EQUALS": [True, False, True, True, False],         
        })

Note that I do not "know" the column names when doing the actual check, and the number of columns can vary between calls.
Is there something like "col_equals" in the Polars API?

pl.n_unique_horizontal would probably be the answer, but it has not yet been added.

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9966

You can use the List API:
df.with_columns(ISO_EQUALS = 
   pl.concat_list(columns_to_check_for_equality).list.n_unique() == 1
)

shape: (5, 5)
┌───────────┬────────────┬────────────┬─────────────┬────────────┐
│ ISO_codes ┆ ISO_codes1 ┆ ISO_codes2 ┆ OtherColumn ┆ ISO_EQUALS │
│ ---       ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---        │
│ str       ┆ str        ┆ str        ┆ str         ┆ bool       │
╞═══════════╪════════════╪════════════╪═════════════╪════════════╡
│ fin       ┆ fin        ┆ fin        ┆ 1           ┆ true       │
│ nor       ┆ nor        ┆ ice        ┆ 2           ┆ false      │
│ eng       ┆ eng        ┆ eng        ┆ 3           ┆ true       │
│ eng       ┆ eng        ┆ eng        ┆ 4           ┆ true       │
│ swe       ┆ eng        ┆ eng        ┆ 5           ┆ false      │
└───────────┴────────────┴────────────┴─────────────┴────────────┘


It's nice and short and indeed pl.n_unique_horizontal would be nice, however it's quite slow. Not sure if due to the transformation or to n_unique itself (in [tag:pandas], nunique is slow).

You could compare all columns to the first one and aggregate with all_horizontal:
all_items.with_columns(pl.all_horizontal(
                          pl.col(columns_to_check_for_equality)
                            .eq(pl.col(columns_to_check_for_equality[0]))
                         ).alias('ISO_EQUALS')
                      )

Output:
┌───────────┬────────────┬────────────┬─────────────┬────────────┐
│ ISO_codes ┆ ISO_codes1 ┆ ISO_codes2 ┆ OtherColumn ┆ ISO_EQUALS │
│ ---       ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---        │
│ str       ┆ str        ┆ str        ┆ str         ┆ bool       │
╞═══════════╪════════════╪════════════╪═════════════╪════════════╡
│ fin       ┆ fin        ┆ fin        ┆ 1           ┆ true       │
│ nor       ┆ nor        ┆ ice        ┆ 2           ┆ false      │
│ eng       ┆ eng        ┆ eng        ┆ 3           ┆ true       │
│ eng       ┆ eng        ┆ eng        ┆ 4           ┆ true       │
│ swe       ┆ eng        ┆ eng        ┆ 5           ┆ false      │
└───────────┴────────────┴────────────┴─────────────┴────────────┘

timing on 5M rows
# pl.all_horizontal(pl.col(columns_to_check_for_equality).eq(pl.col(columns_to_check_for_equality[0])))
15.9 ms ± 983 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# pl.concat_list(columns_to_check_for_equality).list.n_unique() == 1
6.67 s ± 194 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

